# simple dsl modem, static ip, and pppoe config challenge

Tags: router, static-ip, pppoe

I'm in China and our new DSL broadband is a super cut-rate Huawei box that takes an optical input and has 4 LAN ports. You can set the box's 192.168.X.1, and then it expects the four LAN inputs to be static manually assigned IPs on the same range. In order to sign on you must open a PPPoE connection on a terminal. The unit does not support DHCP or PPPoE itself.

I want to set up a wireless router that can keep the PPPoE alive, but both the linksys and Volans I have can EITHER do a static IP or PPPoE connection, not both at once.

The linksys supports static IP and PPPoE *passthrough*, which allowed me to connect to it via wireless and then using a "broadband connection" on the desktop open up the PPPoE and get internet access, but other wireless users could not simultaneously log on AND any mobile devices were unable to use that method.

My thinking now is to go Huawei box -> Linksys (static IP & PPPoE passthrough) -> Volans (PPPoE and DHCP) but I'm leery about the kind of service quality I'll get with nested DHCP and it seems like a port-forwarding nightmare.

The alternative is to request a better modem from the provider, but as this is a 2nd tier Chinese city the odds they'll have anything better are low.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put dd-wrt on anything? http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

Comment: I can load dd-wrt on the linksys router. I'll flash it tonight and have a look.

Comment: Then you should be able to do a static ip with PPPoE, NAT and DHCP to the local network.

Comment: I've flashed DD-WRT successfully but don't see an option for static ip w/ pppoe.

Comment: The pppoe settings only have a username and password. The static IP are under WAN settings. Two different screens.